# FreeRDP - launch an application with command line argument

Tags: freerdp, xfreerdp, rdp

I want to launch a Windows application via FreeRDP with command line arguments.
I tried:

```
xfreerdp -v 192.168.1.100 -u myuser -p mypassword -app 'c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe' -app-cmd 'c:\test\test.txt'
```

and

```
xfreerdp -v 192.168.1.100 -u myuser -p mypassword -app 'c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe' -app-file 'c:\test\test.txt'
```

but every time notepad with a blank file starts. I also tried using double backslashes in file path and slashes - all with the same result.

The test.txt file of course exists. If I run `notepad c:\test\test.txt` from `Start->Run` then notepad opens this file correctly.

How do I pass command line arguments to remote app in FreeRDP? I am running FreeRDP 2.0.0.